# Replace Thermistor with Thermocouple in a circuit

Tags: sensor, relay, temperature

I had a simple temperature controlling relay board ([Novus N321](https://www.novusautomation.com/site/default.asp?Idioma=1&TroncoID=608027&SecaoID=818294&SubsecaoID=945100&Template=../catalogos/layout_produto.asp&ProdutoID=739171#)). It would open or close a circuit powering a heater based on the reading of a thermocouple, versus a set value. The circuit is now broken. I was browsing replacements and saw a really cheap one ([W1209](http://www.kelco.rs/katalog/images/17670.pdf)), however, that one employs a thermistor (an "NTC sensor"). And I would prefer to keep using my thermocouple.

Is it possible to simply replace its thermistor with the thermocouple?

If not, how worthwhile would it be to adapt the new circuit to the thermocouple?  Note that in my country a replacement for the original is about $75, and the cheaper one is $5. Also, I have almost no knowledge or experience in electronics.

Comment: No, and probably not worth the effort. Just use the thermistor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but it gets complex, you would end up needing a circuit like this, just for your use case that 3R resistor would be a much higher value,

This is a constant resistance circuit, you feed it with a PWM signal (the output of the top left op amp), and you get a consistent resistance, the bottom left op amp is just a current limit, you can likely omit it for your use case,

then you might have an op amp to amplify your thermocouple voltage, feed it to some cheap micro, or work out an analog way of converting it to a suitable PWM %

As to how it works, the circuit is a modification on a constant current load, and with the input being a % of the load voltage tracks linearly. if the voltage across the output decreases, the current set point drops by the same amount, so it behaves like a resistance.

[image]